# php login issue reported in chrome

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am writing a simple login script in php however it is reporting that there is an error on line 40. Personally, as an absolute beginner, I cant spot it. As far as I know everything else should be working fine but if there is anything else wrong please let me know. Any help?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    $dbHost = "mysql.**************.co.uk";        //Location Of Database usually its localhost 
    $dbUser = "r****2";            //Database User Name 
    $dbPass = "********";            //Database Password 
    $dbDatabase = "***********";    //Database Name 

    $db = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass)or die("Error connecting to database."); 
    //Connect to the databasse 
    mysql_select_db($dbDatabase, $db)or die("Couldn't select the database."); 
    //Selects the database 

    /* 
    The Above code can be in a different file, then you can place include'filename.php'; instead. 
    */ 

    //Lets search the databse for the user name and password 
    //Choose some sort of password encryption, I choose sha256 
    //Password function (Not In all versions of MySQL). 
    $usr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $pas = hash('sha256', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])); 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_table  
        WHERE username='$usr' AND 
        password='$pas' 
        LIMIT 1"); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1);{ 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; 
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['first_name']; 
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $row['last_name']; 
        $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE; 
        header("Location: users_page.php"); // Modify to go to the page you would like 
        exit; 
    }
    }else{
        header("Location: login_page.php"); 
        exit; 

}else{    //If the form button wasn't submitted go to the index page, or login page 
    header("Location: index.php");     
    exit; 
} 
?>
```

Many thanks

Comment: You'll at the very least need to tell us *which* error you are getting, and which is line 40.

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1);{` `;` take it out if you want your code to "live" - grin

Comment: remove the semicolon in if statement

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1);{
```

Remove the semi-colon

See the other answer for another error on curly bracket closing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra closing bracket here:

```
    exit; 
}
}else{
```

Should be

```
    exit; 
}else{
```

Comment: No, that bracket is fine. He needs to remove the semi-colon after mysql_num_rows().

Comment: after removing the ;   I get this error message - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/r*****2/***************.co.uk/tut/Login/verify.php on line 40

Comment: line 40 is the final 'else'

Answer (score 0):

You have two open-ended else calls at the end of your function

```
}else{
        header("Location: login_page.php"); 
        exit; 

}else{    //If the form button wasn't submitted go to the index page, or login page 
    header("Location: index.php");     
    exit; 
}
```

Remove one or put a conditional if statement on one.  Also take the ";" out of

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1);{
```